# codingBat question: Returns true if for every '*' (star) in the string

Tags: java

i am working on this codingbat question:
Returns true if for every '*' (star) in the string, if there are chars both immediately before and after the star, they are the same.
Example:

```
sameStarChar("xy*yzz") → true
sameStarChar("xy*zzz") → false
sameStarChar("*xa*az") → true
```

My first attempt of code is :

```
public boolean sameStarChar(String str) {
  //boolean flag = false;

  for(int i =1;i< str.length()-1; i++){
    if(str.charAt(i) == '*' && str.charAt(i-1) == str.charAt(i+1)){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

and did not pass few case such: sameStarChar("12*2*3*") → false , sameStarChar("XY*YYYY*Z*") → false.

However, if changed the code to:

```
public boolean sameStarChar(String str) {
  //boolean flag = false;

  for(int i =1;i< str.length()-1; i++){
    if(str.charAt(i) == '*' && str.charAt(i-1) != str.charAt(i+1)){
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

The result is corrected. I do not understand what is wrong with my first attempt.

Comment: How do you expect your first attempt to fail for `12*2*3*` when it already exits the whole check with result `true` after the first * is fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second attempt you fixed the only problem you had with your code.

Your first attempt will be **immediately terminate by returning `true`, if there is an `*` surrounded by matching chars**. (Here you will miss out the upcoming `*`s with mismatching chars)

Your second case now will **check whether your string contain an `*` which is surrounded by mismatching chars, and terminate it by returning false.**

NOTE: This is an example where you align your checks to detect the negative scenario rather than traversing all and finding the positive ones.

In your case you can do two things (NOTE: we can safely remove the corner two, and you already done that),

Return `true` if : Every `*` in the string is surrounded by matching chars

OR

Return `false` if : There is at least one `*` which is surrounded by a mismatching chars.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues with your first attempt:

- It fails to consider the case of a string that doesn't contain any asterisks at all, for which the loop will run to completion and then `false` will incorrectly be returned.
- It incorrectly returns `true` on the first pair of matched neighbours of an asterisk, regardless of any unmatched pairs that may follow.

Answer (score 0):

In your first case, you are returning as soon as you find one valid match/occurrence which is wrong. Also, you are not checking for the cases where there are `*` at one or either ends.

In the second case, you are searching explicitly for mismatches. Also, the corner cases of `*` at ends naturally becomes a match/success.